# How to stop TOP Scroll Load in jQuery Endless Scroll plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infinite-loop, endlessscroll

I am trying to create infinite loop for my website. I am using **jQuery Endless Scroll plugin** for that.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.endless-scroll.js'></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).endlessScroll({
        inflowPixels: 300,
                ceaseFireOnEmpty :false,
        callback: function() {
            var $img = $('#clmn-a .box:nth-child(4)').clone();
            $('#clmn-a').append($img);
        }
    });
});
```

Everything is working fine, but this function is running on top scroll also. I want to load data only when user reach near the footer. So how to disable Top Scroll Load in **jQuery Endless Scroll plugin**

PluginLink: https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll

Comment: Could you provide a link to the plugin or a pen/fiddle

Comment: I update the question with link. Please Check

Comment: How about using an alternative plugin like http://jscroll.com/ instead of using this one?

Comment: Is it allow to load data before user touch the footer? is it mobile friendly? Can I use Top Scroll also in it?

Comment: Yes you should be able to get what you're looking for. But take a look at the examples and make sure.

Comment: Thank You Isbel. I will try this too.

Comment: You're welcome and happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    EndlessScroll.prototype.detectScrollDirection = function() {
        var currentScrollTop;
        this.didScroll = true;
        currentScrollTop = $(this.target).scrollTop();
        if (currentScrollTop > this.lastScrollTop) {
          this.scrollDirection = 'next';
        }
        else{
        }
        return this.lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
      };


    $(window).endlessScroll({
        inflowPixels: 300,
                ceaseFireOnEmpty :false,
        callback: function() {
            var $img = $('#clmn-a .box:nth-child(4)').clone();
            $('#clmn-a').append($img);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Its Working. Thank You Ramesh!